# Conda commands don't show anything

Tags: anaconda, conda

I installed Anaconda and it installed fine - I even edited my .bashrc file the way it needs to be, however, when I entered "conda" commands in my terminal to check if it installed correctly, it doesn't display anything (Like in the image). I am using Ubuntu 14.04.
* Please refer the link for viewing the image - I can't post an image unless I have 10 reputation.
[Image of the errror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzoKF.png)

Answer (score 1):

Your [bashrc](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/260941/add-path-to-bashrc) file is normally updated with anaconda upon install.  If you want to check or enter it manually it should look like,

```
PATH=/home/<user>/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
```

once it's there, source your bashrc file

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

you should now be able to use conda at the command line. More info about

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however, the issue stays. I had already updated my .bashrc. I just ended up downloading the python3 and adding the kernel for python2.

Comment: what about running it with the full path?  `~/anaconda3/bin/conda`.  is anaconda2 working?  if it is then perhaps your anaconda3 installation is bad.